# Combine 2x 16 bit into 1x 32 bit (Mitsubishi)

Tags: plc

As the title suggests, I am having a problem trying to figure out how to combine 2x 16 bit into 1x 32 bit, can anyone point me in the right direction? Cheers in advance

Comment: Combine in what regard? Just move them into a 32-bit register side-by-side? Or represent a third number derived from the original two in some fashion? I'm not familiar with Mitsubishi PLCs in particular, but the former could be achieved by shifting one value 16 bits to the left and the ORing the other value (in a 32-bit register, of course).

Answer (score 0):

From a mathematical standpoint you can do

```
32 bit word = (high word * 65536) + low word
```

Comment: Cheers matey, I managed to get it sorted eventually, turns out that the 16 bit words were signed...